# docker complain I have a bridge name conflict with a invisible network

Tags: docker, configuration, network-interface

When I reboot machine disabled the docker.service, I do not have br1 in my ip a output.

However, after start docker, the br1 appears.

But `sudo docker network inspect` does not show any related network.

```
Error response from daemon: cannot create network 33618cb1603a773a11d97750182fde9d8feb98c03a9882bb0c4539c3ea3fbe1d (br1): conflicts with network aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106 (br1): networks have same bridge name

sudo docker network inspect aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106
[]
Error response from daemon: network aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106 not found
```

So where is this network, how can I find it?

I did `sudo docker network prune`, now only 3 entry left. But br1 is still created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when removing Docker network fails
with bridge record left in database. 
Database location is `/var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db` (AlmaLinux). 
Although the usual suggestion is to stop Docker, delete this database and then rebuild containers, this isn't the best solution for larger infrastructure. 
In this case, a better solution is
removing the leftover bridge record from database.
This could be done by using boltcli tool (https://github.com/spacewander/boltcli).

1. Assuming that go is installed, install boltcli:
   `go install github.com/spacewander/boltcli@latest`
2. Make a copy of local-kv.db and open it with boltcli:
   `boltcli /path_to_db_copy/local-kv.db`
3. List buckets to get one to work with:
   `buckets *`
   Most probably, bucket is "libnetwork"
4. Find key based on id (or part of it) of the conflicting network (aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106 from the question)

   `keys libnetwork *aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106*`
5. Use returned key (probably, "docker/network/v1.0/bridge/aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106/") to remove record

   `del libnetwork docker/network/v1.0/bridge/aed743fd32b35084f5ccee11e4cfb631b31dccb2fec79cba60cd5f4252b03106/`
6. Exit boltcli (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>),
   stop Docker and overwrite the original db file with the altered one
   (making a copy of the original is recommended before doing it). 
   Start Docker.

Comment: I wonder why `removing Docker network fails with bridge record left in database` can even happen? I would like to prevent this from happening than mitigating it.

Comment: I have spent time trying to find solution without removing whole database and read several similar problem descriptions. From that I made two conclusions: this problem is quite rare and from cases I saw, there is no way to reproduce some actions to cause it. For me it happened during mailcow:dockerized update. And I do not see how to prevent this. Probably Docker will just get a fix over time.